# Notation of sequence made from sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have two sets of $n$ $d$-dimensional vectors $X$ and $Y$. So I can compute the Earth Mover's Distance (EMD), or Wasserstein metric, between them:

$\delta_1 = \operatorname{EMD}(X, Y)$

Now I have two groups of three sets of $n$ vectors $X_1, X_2, X_3$ and $Y_1, Y_2, Y _3$.

1. I want to compute $\delta_2 = \operatorname{EMD}(\cdot)$ between all $X_i$ and all $Y_i$ as defined above. How do I note that these sets are combined? If I would write $X_1 ∪ X_2 ∪ X_3$, I would end up with less than $3n$ elements if two of the three sets contain the same element.
2. I actually need to do a weighted EMD computation, which means that all elements of $X_1, Y_1$ are assigned weight $2$, while for all others, the weight is $1$. I could define a weight vector $w = (2 ··· 2, 1 ··· 1, 1 ··· 1)$ that is symmetrically used for both inputs of $\operatorname{EMD}_w(\cdot)$. However for this to work, the sets need to stay in order.

Is there any concise notation for this?

Comment: I don't understand. You say you have three sets, but it seems like there are six... how many vectors are in each set ?

Comment: I have a two groups of three sets each. In each set, I have $n$ vectors. The EMD computes a distance between two multisets. I compute the distance between the two groups however. I clarified my question, sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i can understand your question, the best would be to define everything in terms of sequences : $x_1=(x_1^k)_{1\leq k \leq n}$, $x_2=(x_2^k)_{1\leq k \leq n}$, $x_3=(x_3^k)_{1\leq k \leq n}$, $y_1=(y_1^k)_{1\leq k \leq n}$, $y_2=(y_2^k)_{1\leq k \leq n}$, $y_3=(y_3^k)_{1\leq k \leq n}$, define the concatenation operation : 
$$(x_1,\ldots,x_p) \circ (y_1,\ldots,y_q) = (x_1,\ldots,x_p,y_1,\ldots,y_q)$$
and the quantity you're looking for should be
$$EMD(x_1\circ x_1 \circ x_2 \circ x_3, y_1\circ y_1 \circ y_2 \circ y_3).$$

Comment: Do you think there is a good way to define the two sequences first, without defining six sequences (each corresp. to a set)? As we only need inter-set enumerability.

Comment: Or could we make it a multiset of pairs (x_i, w_i) maybe?

Comment: I don't know any way which isn't more or less equivalent to defining sequences...

Comment: What I mean is how can I write sequence a consists of sets X1,X2,X3? without defining sequences x1, x2, x3. Because I already have the sets and use them elsewhere.